# As3 - script work at root timeline but not inside MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

Please help me inspect this code:

```
function btntxt(target:String, txt:String):void
{
    var button:MovieClip = MovieClip(this.getChildByName(target));
**  var btnText:TLFTextField = TLFTextField(button.getChildByName("btnText"));
    btnText.text = txt;
    button.gotoAndStop(1);
    button.buttonMode = true;
    button.useHandCursor = true;
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,overListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,outListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clickListener);
    button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upListener);
}
```

When I debug, it gives me error at **:

1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TLFTextField.

1180: Call to a possibly undefined method TLFTextField.

Also output error 1065. This code works at the top level but when I copy it inside a Movieclip's timeline, it doesn't work! Why?

If this information is short, please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the import statement at the top of your code:

```
import fl.text.TLFTextField;
```

Comment: I have one more question, I did put the import on the top level, but I tried again inside the MovieClip and it worked. Do you need to import everytime you use the code?

Comment: @DanielCheung You should have to `import` the class within each context.